# Using Rattle on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: r, xcode, macos, osx-yosemite, rattle

I am having trouble loading rattle on my mac, I have been pushed around to download X11 but cant seem to find a working page.
When trying to invoke rattle with the simple

```
library(rattle)
```

It has a popup about X11 and continue brings you yo this link https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201341.

And I get this when trying to use the Rcmdr work around

```
library(Rcmdr)
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so
  Reason: image not found
In addition: Warning message:
running command ''/usr/bin/otool' -L '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/tcltk/libs//tcltk.so'' had status 1 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rcmdr’
xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.
library(Rcmdr)
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: X11 library is missing: install XQuartz from xquartz.macosforge.org
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rcmdr’
install.packages("XQuartz")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning message:
package ‘XQuartz’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1) 
install.packages("tcltk")
Warning message:
package ‘tcltk’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
```

Any help here on getting Rattle to load with OS X Yosemite?

Answer (score 0):

XQuartz isn't an R package, but rather an implementation of the X11 windowing system for Mac OS X. You need to install XQuartz to use the **tcltk** package in R, on which the **Rcmdr** depends, under Mac OS X.

See [the Rcmdr installation notes for Mac OS X](http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/Rcmdr/installation-notes.html).

I hope this helps,
 John

Comment: Yes thank you! The site to download XQuartz was down during this time once it was back up everything has been running smoothly.